# Why do I get an error in an empty project?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run a newly created project in Android Studio it shows me this error:

```
E/Perf: Fail to get file list user.example.com.prueba
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list user.example.com.prueba
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

These are the data from my Android Studio:

```
Android Studio 3.5.2
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832, built on October 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to add this ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
` permission and run again.

Comment: Hi mate, does it fix the issue? I think it does not really fix it, intermittent crash so really hard to re-produce.

Comment: Adding "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" does not fix it.

Comment: you can try in another device, it's working on me